# « Regarde ce que fait ce scientifique » vs « Regarde ce que ce scientifique a fait »

Tags: grammaire

Why does changing the subordinate clause (can an indirect object be a subordinate clause?) to the present indicative from the *passé composé* change the position of the conjugated “faire” in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Subordinate clause doesn't have an impact on conjugation.

"Regarde ce que ce scientifique fait." or "Regarde ce que fait ce scientifique."

"Regarde ce que ce scientifique a fait." or "Regarde ce qu'a fait ce scientifique."

It's just a matter of order : subject + verb OR verb + subject

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.  The order is free.

> *Regarde ce que ce scientifique fait.*
> *Regarde ce qu'a fait ce scientifique.*

The inversion often sounds more "elegant".

[image]

The same freedom of choice exists at least in Spanish which shows a very similar pattern:

[image]

However, the order is mandatory if a pronoun is used:

> *Regarde ce qu'il fait.*
> *<s>Regarde ce que fait-il</s>.*

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you. The versions in my original post seem a little more natural, at least to me. I suspect this is a pronunciation / ""how the sentence flows" issue then. I suppose my follow-up question is: why is this construction free?

Comment: Because nothing forbids it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this has continued to bother me and I finally discovered why this construction is "free."

I grew up around French speakers so I generally know what "sounds" correct, even if I don't know why (useful, but frustrating!).

This sentence is an example of "stylistic inversion." This has been driving me crazy. I was able to form other sentences where this inversion was possible and I realized that it must have something to do with the presence of a relative pronoun. (I owe this to Fréro Delavega and Kendji Girac and their love for phrases beginning with "quand viennent...")

Stylistic inversion can be used in 3 cases:

1. After a relative pronoun / indefinite relative pronoun (my example)
2. After a comparison
3. To emphasize the subject, often used in poetry (Kendji and Fréro Delavega)

Extra reading for those who are curious:

https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/inversion-with-nouns/

https://www.thoughtco.com/uses-of-french-inversion-4086442

https://www.jstor.org/stable/4178083

Comment: You should have edited your question or better, asked a new question. This reply doesn't answer to the question asked but to a follow up question that only appeared in comments.